# Problem with facebook showPermissionDialog

Tags: facebook, permissions, dialog

I am able to use this funciton to pop up the dialog. It works fine if the user hasn't granted any permission. After I granted the permission, I refresh the whole application page, the permission dialog show and disappear. Just after the dialog disappeared, it started to redirect to the home page www.facebook.com.

I have checked my setting and I found no problem? Does anyone have any ideas of what the problem is.

Comment: Can you post a link to your application or post your implementation code? Can't really assess the issue without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to correctly specify the xd_receiver.htm file.

Comment: this is more of a guess than a solution